# SourceTree: remote branch to pull list is empty

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-pull, sourcetree

I'm trying to pull data from remote, but list of branches is empty:
[image]
[image]

The issue observed only on Windows client, no problems on OSX.
`git pull` is working well.
Also, this issue happens with any repositories. Other actions, such as fetch, commit, push, are working ok.

Where is the problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. 
So i checked Settings and came to the remotes tab and there it was!
origin with an empty value of Path, no idea how this happend but this was the case for me. 
So i added the Path again and pressed refresh in the pull popup and there it was, a filled list of branches.

Comment: I had the same issue - but remote list turned empty only **after closing the repo in Sourctree and opening it back**. Before closing, the remote path showed up in Repository Settings and in the config file, Push, Pull, Fetch worked nicely ... except that remote branches list was empty and "REMOTES" on the left showed only "origin". Sourcetree v 2.6.10